# Grunt: Compile pages in multiple languages (Translation)

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have a very simple issue but still am unable to find any solution.
My site should be "shipped" (= grunt publish) in 2 languages in 2 different folders.

#### What I imagine

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <. hello_world />
</body>
</html>
```

`translation.json`

```
translation: [
    hello_world: [
        en: "Hello World!",
        de: "Hallo Welt!"
    ]
]
```

#### Should then be compiled to

`en/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

`de/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    Hallo Welt!
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know such a grunt task?

Answer (score 0):

To anybody interested in doing the same, there is [angular-gettext](http://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/) / grunt-angular-gettext that can do that.

I chose [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/) in the end anyways, since it compiles only 1 version of your site including all languages meaning the user can change the language at runtime.

Comment: angular-gettext can switch languages at runtime too. It can put all the [translations into one file](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/compile/) or do [lazy loading](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/lazy-loading/) similar to how angular-translate does that.

Comment: I didn't know that angular-gettext supported lazy loading. Would've been a better choice then, feature-wise. However the project is finished and we are not developing any further.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any ready-made solutions available that can do this. You could use the [grunt-angular-gettext](https://github.com/rubenv/grunt-angular-gettext) [extract](https://github.com/rubenv/grunt-angular-gettext/blob/master/tasks/extract.js) and [compile](https://github.com/rubenv/grunt-angular-gettext/blob/master/tasks/compile.js) tasks to pull all the strings out that you need translated and make the json files you need.

However I couldn't find anything already out there to compile the html and insert the translations for you. Most of the code exists in the [angular-gettext project](https://github.com/rubenv/angular-gettext). You'd need to modify it and run the code in a task instead of in angular at runtime.

If you went this route your index.html might look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <span translate>Hello World!</span>
</body>
</html>
```

The code for loading the strings is in the `setStrings` function in the `catalog.js` [here](https://github.com/rubenv/angular-gettext/blob/master/src/catalog.js) and the function to retrieve a string is named `getString`.

Not an ideal solutions, but it's something.

Answer (score 0):

I found a grunt task that does this:
https://github.com/claudetech/grunt-i18n-static